# TFS work Item editing conflict (TFS error 237079)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-sdk

It seems that TFS doesn't handle concurrent work item editing very well.
We ran into two problematic scenarios:

Scenario A:

1. You start editing a work item.
2. While you're editing, someone else edits and saves the same item.
3. When you try to save you get the horrible TFS237079 error which which means you have to loose your changes, refresh the item and edit again. nice.

Scenario B:

1. You have a work item focused for a while.
2. Someone edits and saves the item.
3. When you start editing you're actually editing an outdated version of the work item and will get TFS23709 when trying to save.

I'm quite familiar with the TFS SDK (wrote some TFS VS Addon and custom work item controls) but can't find something like a "BeforeEdit" event for a work item.

Having such event would allow me to warn the user that someone else is currently editing (for scenario A) and get the latest revision before editing (for Scenario B).

Thanks,
Raviv.

Comment: Rajiv, check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.beforeworkitemsupdate.aspx. Would this help you?

Comment: Don't think so, because this is an API for version control, not work item tracking. 
Also, I need to check the work item revision and status **before** the user starts editing.

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic concurrency is what it is. The server isnt tracking who is editing work items so If you really wanted to do "Someone else is editing this item" notifications you would probably have to write your own services and custom controls to track it. You'd also have to deal with edit flags not being release if visual studio crashed and with the web UI.  If you choose that path I wish you luck!